# Nginx websocket will work for a single response or not at all, seemly at random

Tags: unity-game-engine, asp.net-core, nginx, websocket, signalr

I've been working with SignalR on Asp.net core 3 over Nginx to network a Unity3d app. On my local build through Kestral, websockets work great. However, once I proxy my WebApp through nginx,  my websocket will work for a single response or not at all, seemly at random. Thoughts?

My current nginx build config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ip domain.com www.domain.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name ip domain.com www.domain.com;

        # SSL Configuration
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        #make sure to check for more up to date ciphers
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        root /var/www/html;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep_alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }


        location /notifications {

                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/notifications/;
                include             /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                set $http_upgrade "websocket";
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_read_timeout 3600;

                proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
                proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_buffers 8 32k;
                proxy_buffer_size 64k;
       }

        location ~^/identity {
                rewrite ^/identity/login? /login/ break;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi @re-fuse, writing a first post is not easy. In my opinion you might want to consider to provide more information to the community instead of just pasting around a configuration file. For example, when you stated that it randomly works you might give more detail on that. In addition, you might want to state what you already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @RonaldRink'd-fens' Hey! Thank you for the response. I added an answer below. This was an issue with the underline Nginx behavior. This behavior did not exist in earlier builds as my proxy setting worked prior to this post. Makes me believe this is a recent behavior update.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:
After enabling the debug logs for signalr, I discovered that my websocket was being downgraded to HTTP 1.0 which explained why I received responses from the server only once or not all when using websockets.

My application (Unity Game) supports both protocols and if you review my config you will find both a "location /" block and "location /notifications" block configured to HTTP and Websockets, respectively. My application uses http to authenticate and websockets to actually play the game. As such, Nginx persisted the original http proxy headers after authentication through http and then calling the "/notifications" endpoint despite it being setup for websockets (The behavior I expect was a new websocket connection based on my configuration to be created).

Fix:
I changed my "location/ " (my regular http endpoint) block headers to support HTTP 1.1 like so:

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }
```

## Cleaned up websocket block based on asp.net core documentation:

```
    location /notifications {

            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/notifications/;
           # include             /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            # Configure WebSockets
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_cache off;

            # Configure ServerSentEvents
            proxy_buffering off;

            # Configure LongPolling
            proxy_read_timeout 100s;
        

           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  $
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
```

After this edit, both my HTTP and websocket endpoints worked as expected. I'm not sure why the headers were persisted into the websocket "location /notifications" block but I'm sure there is some nuanced Nginx documentation on it somewhere.

Hope this helps someone in the future.